# Ehcache not work in Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

This is my actual approach.

When I refresh my app second by second the Date param always is update.

The controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController implements ToCache {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"})
    @Cacheable(value = "main", key = "#root.method.name")
    public String showHome(HttpServletRequest request) {

        request.setAttribute("now", new Date());
        request.setAttribute("tmp", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

        return "index";
    }

}
```

The interface

```
public interface ToCache {

    String showHome(HttpServletRequest request);

}
```

Ehcache-servlet.xml

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pjcom.**" />

    <!-- Manejador de vistas -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/view/"
          p:suffix=".jsp"
          p:exposeContextBeansAsAttributes="true" />
```

Ehcache integration with Spring

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id ="enhancedDefaultKeyGenerator" class="org.springframework.cache.interceptor.DefaultKeyGenerator"/>

<cache:annotation-driven mode="proxy" 
                         proxy-target-class="true" 
                         cache-manager="cacheManager" 
                         key-generator="enhancedDefaultKeyGenerator"/>

<!-- END EHCACHE -->
```

Ehcache configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" 
         updateCheck="true" 
         monitoring="autodetect" 
         dynamicConfig="true"
         maxBytesLocalHeap="150M">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>    

    <cache name="main"
           maxBytesLocalHeap="100M"
           eternal="false"
           t

imeToIdleSeconds="10"
           timeToLiveSeconds="10"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           maxElementsOnDisk="1000"          
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

</ehcache>
```

The runtime log, deploy and refresh.

```
31-Mar-2014 21:33:20.881 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-52] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Repliegue (undeploy) de la aplicación web que tiene como trayectoria de contexto /springehcache
31-Mar-2014 21:33:20.917 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-53] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Desplieque del descriptor de configuración C:\...\springehcache.xml
31-Mar-2014 21:33:20.919 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-53] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
31-Mar-2014 21:33:22.843 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-50] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springehcache]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of your spring configuration?

Comment: What shoud be cached in this configuration? The request param of your cachable method will be a new on on every invocation - nothing to cache...

Comment: @geoand just I have updated with all configuration.

Comment: @Dirk Lachowski, I can´t caching simple html response?

Comment: I think Dirk is correct! You would just be caching the invocation of the showHome method, which is always "index". Spring MVC then uses that to offload the processing to the view handler, over which you haven't any control.

Comment: What I have to do to can caching simple html method response?